# Using python how do I manage windows on OSX

Tags: python, macos, window-managers, pythonw

I am trying to manage windows using python.

Specifically I am trying to find a window that I have opened using selenium then have it focused and maximise it. I believe this is possible using a window manager as there are programs like qtile written in python.

I have read on the python documentation that there is something called pythonw.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html

I am using python 3.5 but I can upgrade if this is an easier option.

How do I use this on OSX?

Is there a library or are there any more resources on this subject?

I would like to learn how to use simple window management in python for osx.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a system level window manager for this

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: We know that we need a system level window manager for this but this is the question actually, not the answer